How is the turbine in a rocket engine started?
I know that liquid rocket engines use a turbine to drive pumps that lead the Oxidizer and Fuel into the combustion chamber and that this turbine has a combustion chamber called the pre-burner. According to my knowledge, the Oxidizer and Fuel are first pumped into the pre-burner to start the turbine. But how is this Oxidizer and Fuel pumped in the first place with the turbine being off for engines like the RS - 25? do they have separate methods? and if so, what are they?

This is a bit of a broad question. There’s … a variety of different answers depending on which engine. It’s not a short video, but it’s pretty good to get started https://youtube.com/watch?v=bAUVCn_jw5I

have you looked at any of the QAs about e.g. How the Raptor starts?  Those came up pretty recently.

There's a great writeup on starting the SSME in https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19910021905/downloads/19910021905.pdf I don't see much point in summarizing it. If you read it and still have questions I could maybe answer them.

@OrganicMarble I'll surely read it!
